# Passing a function without specifying an argument in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

These two are stateHandlers are equal:

```
const [state, setState] = useState()

  stateHandler = {(newValue) => setState(newValue)} // first way to pass it
  stateHandler = {setState} // second way to pass it
```

Same with onClick - you can pass it both ways

```
const handleClick = (values) => {
// do sth
}

onClick = {handleClick} // same
onClick = {(values) => handleClick(values)} // same
```

Edit:

Based on the comments I will modify my question a bit:

> (values) => handleClick(values) is also a function that calls
> setState, but why are you not asking how that function receives its
> argument?

This is what I am asking here probably, yes. Thank you for pointing me

Comment: Arguments are getting their values when you call the function, not when you define it, an exception being the default values to arguments.

Comment: These examples will only be the same in very specific circumstances, you'll need to provide a concrete example of code you're having trouble with to get accurate help.

Comment: `(values) => handleClick(values)` is also a function that calls `setState`, but why are you not asking how *that* function receives its argument? For the caller there is no difference between calling `handleClick` directly (`{handleClick}`) or calling a function that calls `handeClick` (`{(values) => handleClick(values)}`). The caller only sees a function and it calls that function with an argument. Note: *You* are *not* the caller. React/the browser calls the function when the corresponding event happens.